# how can I mirror on sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

i try to do an animal tail, and whatever i do on one side doesn't go to the other side as well. how can i fix this? 
[image: one size]
[image: the other]

Answer (score 1):

In the *Symmetry/Lock* section, have you enabled a mirror axis?

[image]

Comment: yes.. it's not working